# Espacios en query SEARCH_ACTIONS Android

Tags: java, android, shell, packages

Como agrego espacios al campo query con SEARCH_ACTION en android?
Ejemplo:

FUNCIONA:

```
adb shell am start -a com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION -e query "enviar"  <nombre_paquete>
```

NO FUNCIONA

```
adb shell am start -a com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION -e query "enviar dinero a pedro"  <nombre_paquete>
```

Error:

> Starting: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION
>   pkg=dinero (has extras) } Error: Activity not started, unable to
>   resolve Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION
>   flg=0x10000000 pkg=dinero (has extras) }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por fin encontré la respuesta, solo era necesario agregar "\" en cada separación, así.

```
    adb shell am start -a com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION -e query "enviar\ dinero\ a\ pedro"  <nombre_paquete>
```

Answer (score 1):

En realidad tu aplicación debe funcionar de la misma manera esto probando en el emulador, para que funcione en producción tu aplicación debe estar publicada en Google Play Store.

En realidad el error:

> Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent {
>   act=com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION

**se refiere a que no puede resolver el intent `SEARCH_ACTION`.**

Asegura que esta tengo correctamente definido el `intent-filter`, revisa este ejemplo:

```
  <activity
        android:name=".SearchableActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:value=".SearchableActivity" />

    </activity>
```

Comment: Tal vez no me explique, pero en el parametro **query** cuando escribo "enviar" si funciona puedo ver la respuesta del en la consola pero al agregar "enviar dinero a pedro" no funciona marca el error mencionado.